# Default font in text frames

Tags: fonts, text, scribus

I would like to set a default font for all my text frame (Ideally I would also set that the text is justified). I use scribs 1.5.5 on Mac. I went to Preferences > Item Tools > Text and modified it there. However, when I create a new text frame and start typing, it's still the old font. What else do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

For the current document, you probably need to set the character style of the default paragraph style and / or the default character style.

In this context, the Item tools are only useful for defining the Default styles of future document.

(I've requested a few times this behavior to be changed... but with no success. Sorry.)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can make this change?

Comment: "edit > styles" or F5...

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my life easier. I am self taught with the software and your information was gold